# Generative model to generate hidden activations coming from a previously trained hidden layer

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, autoencoders, generative-models, gan

I need to train a generative model to generate vectors which resemble the activations of a particular hidden layer of a neural network which has been previously trained. In particular, the hidden layer has been previously trained by merging outputs of a recurrent neural network and a convolutional neural network. Is it possible to use a standard Variational Autoencoder to do that? If not, is there a generative model which is better suited to generate them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I don't think anyone will be able to tell you which generative model will work best, so you'll have to try it out for yourself. The paper [Deep Predictive Coding Networks for Video Prediction and Unsupervised Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.08104)
 might be of some interest to you, as they have a network which predicts activations, although not generatively.